# Error trying to sign RPM

Tags: rpm, signing, gnupg, rpmbuild

I am trying to build and sign an RPM.
I created my .rpmmacro file in the location I am building /path/to/macrodir/
Then I am using  --define with _topdir referring to /path/to/macrodir/

If I build the RPM without giving --sign; its working fine.

```
rpmbuild --define "_topdir /path/to/macrodir" -bb spec
```

The .rpmmacro is in macrodir and contains

```
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_name Name (Comment) <emailid>
%_gpgpath pathtognupgfolder
%_gpgbin locationofgpgexec
```

If I include --sign then its throwing the error

```
rpmbuild --define "_topdir /path/to/macrodir" -bb --sign spec
```

error: You must set "%_gpg_name" in your macro file

I am not able to see what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: what was the exact solution @vpram86?

Comment: I ended up avoiding macro file and pass all arguments to rpmbuild through multiple --define.

Comment: ah okay. I must have something else wrong then because I tried that as well and i am still getting errors. thanks for the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this [detailed writeup](http://fedoranews.org/tchung/gpg/) on how to sign custom rpm pacakge.

I faced a different problem, when running the following command it failed complaining no `rpm` file found.

```
rpm --addsign gyum-2.0-5.FC3.i386.rpm
```

After installing `rpmsign` package everything worked.

Answer (score 5):

As the OP mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903688/error-trying-to-sign-rpm#comment50632658_11903688), setting the `%gpg_name` macro via a `--define` flag to `rpm`/`rpmbuild`/`rpmsign` works.

`rpm --define "_gpg_name <your email or name>" --addsign <RPM to sign>`

Comment: On CentOS7, passing --define "_gpg_name <your email or name>" --sign to rpmbuild (v4.11.3) does not work - the error is "You must set "%_gpg_name" in your macro file".

Comment: @GrahamLeggett I just tried it after setting up a second key for a different repo and I didn't get that error in the slightest. So unless that's been changed in a package there is a configuration error on your end.

Answer (score 2):

At least on my machine the file is called .rpmmacros (with an s).

Comment: According to the doc: `Defining any new macros in the ~/.rpmmacros file is not recommended. Such macros would not be present on other machines, where users may want to try to rebuild your package.`